# error Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, openfeint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode Exit Code 1 - Duplicate Symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148466/xcode-exit-code-1-duplicate-symbol)

When I used the OpenFeint SDK library there were more than 1,000 errors, so I changed my files' extension to `.mm`, but now I get this error. Can anybody help me, please?

> ld: duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in /Users/mymac/Faizan
>   /ChefCookMania/build/ChefCookMania.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChefCookMania.build/Objects-normal/i386/MainGameScene.o
>   and /Users/mymac/Faizan
>   /ChefCookMania/build/ChefCookMania.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChefCookMania.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o error Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please read all the error... it not complete error...expand the error

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the symbol `_iToastDuration`
Please check both the files and avoid cyclic imports in `AppDelegate` and `MainGameScene`